# Dynamically add nested stackviews to existing stackview after runtime

Tags: swift3

Swift Newbie here, trying to learn the code. I have a javascript background though. I've designed a simple interface using nested stackviews in the storyboard:
[image]

The hierarchy is

```
Vertical Stack
   -Horizontal Stack   
      -Vertical Stack
        Label
        Textfield
      -Vertical Stack
        Label
        TextField
```

I've basically set up a table like display, that i want to replicate everytime a user clicks the "Add Member button" It needs to duplicate what's there and add it top stack. Add a New horizontal stack composed of two vertical stacks with the label and text fields.

When I press the button nothing happens. No errors either. I used a print to confirm the button event is firing.

here is the controller code:

```
class createCrewController: UIViewController{
    //MARK: Properties

    var memberList:UIStackView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        memberList = view.viewWithTag(1) as! UIStackView!;
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    var rowArray = [UIStackView]()
    //MARK: Actions
    @IBAction func addMemberBTN(_ sender: UIButton) {
        //Create name and TextField
        let nameLabel = UILabel();
        nameLabel.text = "Name";
        let nameTextField = UITextField();
        nameTextField.placeholder = "Enter Name";
        let phoneLabel = UILabel();
        phoneLabel.text = "Name";
        let phoneTextField = UITextField();
        phoneTextField.placeholder = "Enter Phone";
        //Insert them into vertical Stack
        let nameRow = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [nameLabel,nameTextField]);
        nameRow.axis = .vertical;
        let phoneRow = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [phoneLabel,phoneTextField]);
        phoneRow.axis = .vertical;
        let columnView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews:[nameRow,phoneRow]);
        columnView.axis = .horizontal;

        self.memberList.addSubview(columnView);
    }
```